# Why is the Portmanteau test slower in Rcpp than in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

I need to do a power study of the main Portmanteau tests [Article](http://www.clemson.edu/science/departments/mathematical-sciences/documents/technical-reports/gallagher.TR2013.pdf), for this I must evaluate them in different scenarios, sample sizes and different ARMA models (p, q) generating 180 scenarios which takes me close
  6 hours. Program my function in R and Rcpp, however I find the surprise that in C ++, it is slower, my question is why?

[image]

**My R Code:**

```
Portmanteau <- function(x,h=1,type = c("Box-Pierce","Ljun-Box","Monti"),fitdf = 0){
  Ti <- length(x)
  df <- h-fitdf
  ri <- acf(x, lag.max = h, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)
  pi <- pacf(x, lag.max = h, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)
  if(type == "Monti"){d<-0} else{d<-1}
  if(type == "Box-Pierce"){wi <- 1} else{wi <- (Ti+2)/seq(Ti-1,Ti-h)}
  Q <- Ti*(d*sum(wi*identity(ri$acf[-1]^2))+(1-d)*sum(wi*identity(pi$acf^2)))
  pv <- pchisq(Q,df,lower.tail = F)
  result <- cbind(Statistic = Q, df,p.value = pv)
  rownames(result) <- paste(type,"test")
  return(result)
  }
```

**My Rcpp code**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector PortmanteauC(NumericVector x, int h = 1,const char* type = "Box-Pierce" ,int fitdf = 0) {
  Environment stats("package:stats");
  Function acf = stats["acf"];
  Function pacf = stats["pacf"];
  Function na_pass = stats["na.pass"];
  List ri =  acf(x, h, "correlation", false, na_pass);
  List pi =  pacf(x, h, false, na_pass);
  int Ti = x.size();
  int df = h - fitdf;
  double d; 
  NumericVector wi;
  NumericVector rk = ri["acf"];
  NumericVector pk = pi["acf"];
  NumericVector S(h);
  for(int i = 0; i < h; ++i){S[i] = Ti-i-1;}
  rk.erase(0);
  if(strcmp(type,"Monti") == 0){d=0;} else{d=1;}
  if(strcmp(type,"Box-Pierce") == 0){wi = rep(1,h);} else{wi = (Ti+2)/S;}
  double Q = Ti*(d*sum(wi*pow(rk,2)) + (1-d)*sum(wi*pow(pk,2)));
  double pv = R::pchisq(Q,df,0,false);
  NumericVector result(3);
  result[0] = Q;
  result[1] = df;
  result[2] = pv;
  return(result);
}
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
y = arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.5), n = 250)
mod = arima(y, order = c(1,0,0))
res = mod$residuals
```

---

Box-Pierce

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(PortmanteauC(res, h=10, type = "Box-Pierce",fitdf = 1),replications = 500,Portmanteau(res,h = 10, type = "Box-Pierce", fitdf= 1),
    Box.test(res, lag = 10, type = "Box-Pierce", fitdf= 1))[,1:4]

                                                       test replications elapsed relative
3   Box.test(res, lag = 10, type = "Box-Pierce", fitdf = 1)          500    0.17    1.000
2  Portmanteau(res, h = 10, type = "Box-Pierce", fitdf = 1)          500    0.44    2.588
1 PortmanteauC(res, h = 10, type = "Box-Pierce", fitdf = 1)          500    1.82   10.706
```

---

Ljun-Box

```
benchmark(Box.test(res, lag = 5, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf= 1),replications = 500,
Portmanteau(res,h = 5, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf= 1),
PortmanteauC(res,h = 5, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf= 1))[,1:4]
                                                     test replications elapsed relative
1   Box.test(res, lag = 5, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf = 1)          500    0.17    1.000
2  Portmanteau(res, h = 5, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf = 1)          500    0.45    2.647
3 PortmanteauC(res, h = 5, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf = 1)          500    1.84   10.824
```

---

I would have expected Rcpp to be much faster than the byte compiled R.

Comment: Why do you want a C++ version for this?

Comment: I need to look at the power of several Portmanteau tests in different scenarios and with different sample sizes, but it takes too long with R, so I need to speed up the process.

Comment: Did you profile the R code? Which part of your function takes the longest?

Comment: The part that takes more time is a double for, which evaluates the Portmanteau function in the different scenarios and sample sizes. But in the Portmanteau function, I would not know what part is slower.

Comment: Then use a profiler on a single call to the Portmanteau function. Recent RStudio versions even have a GUI interface for that.

Comment: This is **exactly** what Dirk told you! If most you are doing is executing R functions, then stay in R. The execution time for your `Portmanteau` function is below 1ms. Do you really have more the 2e7 scenarios to explain an execution time of over 6 hours? Or are you doing something else in the loop? In my simple tests `arima` was way more expensive than `Portmanteau`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's analyze the performance properties of your R code. Since a individual call is so fast, that the sampling profiler provided by R cannot be used easily, I simply use `repeat()` to repeat the code until interrupted:

```
Portmanteau <- function(x,h=1,type = c("Box-Pierce","Ljun-Box","Monti"),fitdf = 0){
  Ti <- length(x)
  df <- h-fitdf
  ri <- acf(x, lag.max = h, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)
  pi <- pacf(x, lag.max = h, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)
  if(type == "Monti"){d<-0} else{d<-1}
  if(type == "Box-Pierce"){wi <- 1} else{wi <- (Ti+2)/seq(Ti-1,Ti-h)}
  Q <- Ti*(d*sum(wi*identity(ri$acf[-1]^2))+(1-d)*sum(wi*identity(pi$acf^2)))
  pv <- pchisq(Q,df,lower.tail = F)
  result <- cbind(Statistic = Q, df,p.value = pv)
  rownames(result) <- paste(type,"test")
  return(result)
}

set.seed(1)
profvis::profvis({
  repeat({
    y = arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.5), n = 250)
    mod = arima(y, order = c(1,0,0))
    res = mod$residuals
    Portmanteau(res, h = 10, type = "Box-Pierce", fitdf = 1)
  })
})
```

I let it run for about 49s. Part of the graphical output provided in RStudio can be seen here:

[image: profiling output]

We learn from this:

- `arima()` takes about seven times longer than `Portmenteau()`. Depending on the ratio of calls between these two functions, you might be optimizing the wrong function.
- For the `Portmenteau()` call almost the complete time is spend in `pacf()` and `acf()`. These R functions are  also used within your Rcpp code, but with the additional complexitiy of going back to R from C++. This explains why your C++ is slower than your R code.

Comment: Nicely done. And the "No Free Lunch" theorem still holds: code does not get faster just because you _call it from somewhere else_.